# How to combine tiles in a procedurally generated level in 2D tile based maps?

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting, tilemap, optimization

I am developing a 2D tile-based top-down game. It is currently instantiating square objects with a sprite renderer to procedurally generate the map.

Each floor and wall is a 1-unit wide object.

I have two issues with that:

- The memory usage is quite high and it is not efficient (generating
  maps that are more than 300x300 become really slow)
- There are lights glitches when I have multiple lights in the scene.
  The borders of the squares become visible as seen in the picture:

[image]

- Is it possible to combine all my static elements (floor and wall
  tiles) in a Mesh object, or another adequate object for that?
- The floors items do not have colliders, as the walls have a box
  collider. Does it cause an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for second and third question: try following [this aproach](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109687/combining-many-small-colliders-into-larger-ones/109689#109689)  . The post make reference to colliders but you can use it with tiles. Essentialy you can use big rectangular quads to enclose the same tiles like this:

[image]

Using larger quads reduce the tiled light effect.