# Merging box colliders for optimization

Tags: unity, algorithm, collider

Look at the picture.

The figure on the left shows the individual box colliders in green.

The yellow boxes on the right are the results of the optimization of the original box colliders.

What is the algorithm that makes this possible?

[image]

Comment: similar to :  Combining Many Small Colliders into Larger Ones : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109687/combining-many-small-colliders-into-larger-ones/109689#109689

Comment: Also similar to:  [Algorithm for healing multiple rectangles into a smaller number of rectangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129648/algorithm-for-healing-multiple-rectangles-into-a-smaller-number-of-rectangles)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.

Assuming you have a list of `BoxCollider` that need to be combined, you can access each of their `bounds` properties, which consist of the boxes' `center` and `extents`. With this two information in mind, you can easily calculate the minimum and maximum x, y, and z coordinates of the boxes.

The combined `BoxCollider` will have these two corners: [image] and [image]. From upper and lower corners, you can calculate the center and extents of the combined `BoxCollider`.

All you need to do later is remove or disable initial `BoxCollider`s in your list.

Comment: Can't you just manually edit the box colliders and make it bigger ?

Comment: @Shashimee I believe the OP is asking for dynamically merging the colliders. Otherwise it's not called merging, it's simply resizing a collider.