# Is a simple PolygonCollider2D really worse than several BoxCollider2Ds?

Tags: unity, performance, collider, polygoncollider2d

In my scene I have very simple quadrilateral blocks, which I'm considering using `PolygonCollider2D` for. These blocks will be the building blocks of the scenery so there will be **a lot** of them, and I'd like to use the most efficient technique for them. Now, since I don't really know what kind of optimization Unity does for collisions, I was wondering: would rotating and combining several `BoxCollider2D`s be more efficient? And is a quadrilateral `BoxCollider2D` even worse than a rotated `BoxCollider2D` (which from a mathematical point of view wouldn't be able to apply an AABB collision scheme either) in the first place?

Comment: "These blocks will be the building blocks of the scenery so there will be a lot of them" This sounds like a recipe for trouble. I know a lot of games *look* like they're made out of hundreds or thousands of independent square objects, but that's rarely the truth under the hood. Usually they'll [combine adjacent colliders into larger contiguous rectangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/144728/39518) or an edge collider chain tracing just the outermost perimeter.

Comment: But "is X more demanding than Y?" is generally a question you can answer for yourself much faster and with higher confidence than waiting for Internet hearsay on the matter. Just build a test scene with gobs of box colliders and profile it. Then try a scene with gobs of polygon colliders. The results will tell you not only which is more efficient in the abstract, but which is more efficient for your specific use case on your target hardware. Much more directly applicable than advice you'll find online.

Comment: @DMGregory Hm, combining them all into a single one sounds good. But I'm not sure the answer you linked will be applicable if I have blocks which are not all aligned (I have blocks going up and down to create more diverse paths in the level), except if I used an Edge Collider. But in my experience relying on collisions doesn't work well for stuff like "seeing if the player is grounded", as it's not really consistent whether the collision actually keeps taking place when he stays on a certain block.

Comment: That's an entirely separate concern, usually solved by some form of raycasting, which works no matter what kind of collision representation you use.

Comment: Hm, actually the Unity Standard Assets Project says it uses the overlapCircleAll method just because it doesn't want to modify the layers (as they're meant to be assets to be reused on other projects with different settings), so I'm not sure that's the way... especially if there are many items, that method is gonna do a lot of checks and be really expensive, isn't it?

Comment: Remember, the answer to "is this expensive?" is "profile it!"

Comment: @DMGregory I don't agree 100% with this statement. When profiling, many things can happen that make something seem less expensive. If we have mathematical reasons why something works better in certain cases, it's a better approach to start by following those. Of course at the end of the day I'll just see if it goes well for my use case, but you also have to count that in these beginning phases with few characters and platforms on screen, a profiling doesn't necessarily give away the truth about how a certain solution will perform in the final version.

Comment: It sounds like you're not profiling correctly. Do a stress test with hundreds of colliders and dozens of characters doing ground  check to test the extreme end. Chances are, you'll find performance is still adequate (physics engines' broadphase passes are made to quickly narrow down the potential colliding pairs to the few that matter) and you can proceed with your game after doing this 5 minute test, keeping an eye on the profiler in case performance changes in an unexpected way as you continue making further developments.

Comment: Yeah that's mostly true. I was wondering whether you had some reference for a standard way of implementing the raycast-based ground-check aside from the standard assets project though. And since this seemed to not be the case, what's a case in which the "merging adjacent colliders" technique is used?