# How to turn adjacent squares on a grid into larger rectangles?

Tags: algorithm

I want to know what's the best way to combine individual squares on a grid (tilemap) into larger rectangles. I need this to simplify my physics collision detection/resolution, so that collision doesn't get calculated for each individual tile, but rather for these chunks. I hope you get what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Algorithm for "healing" multiple rectangles into a smaller number of rectangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129648/39518) / [Combining Many Small Colliders into Larger Ones](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109687/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory they do, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad. I've closed this question as a duplicate of those. If you find you need help beyond what's in those Q&A threads, you can post a new question, or edit this one and we can re-open it.

Comment: @DMGregory alright, thanks!